# tsv-summarize: command not found

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

I downloaded the eBay tsv-utils and after following the steps I got this error and I'm not sure what to do.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils.git
$ cd tsv-utils
$ make
```

Make gave me some errors:

```
make[1]: dmd: Command not found
make[1]: *** [../makeapp.mk:18: /home/sylvia/Downloads/tsv-utils/bin/csv2tsv] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sylvia/Downloads/tsv-utils/csv2tsv'
make: *** [makefile:96: csv2tsv] Error 2
```

The command csv2tsv works but when I use the command tsv-summarize it says:

```
tsv-summarize: command not found
```

I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have not installed the D compiler: Please download the D compiler from here: https://dlang.org/download.html.

If you just want to install tsv-utils however, you can download a pre-built binary from the project's github page: https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils/releases/tag/v2.1.2